# How do I get sensor readings of an android mobile (eg. accelerometer, gyroscope, GPS, Camera feed) using app?

Tags: android, android-studio, gps

I want to make an app which takes all the readings of the android phone such as accelerometer, gps, gyroscope, Camera feed etc. Log all of this data and send it to the cloud to a server for usage.

I am a beginner android developer and want to basically understand how to take readings from all the sensors available in the mobile phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here are some references for your understanding. Basically when you talk about `Sensors` as you said `Accelerometer` and `Gyroscope`.

So this how you take control of `Sensors`

```
Sensor accelerometer;
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) != null) {
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No sensor available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Likewise you can take handle of all the available sensors in device.

> Make sure you check whether the sensor is available in device.

Now when we talk about `Camera` and `GPS` they are not `Sensors` they are `Hardware`

So you need hardware permission to take control of `Camera` like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

And to know more about `Camera` refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

Similar, `GPS` is to fetch user location I recommend you to read the entire `Location` Documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html)

Hope this help...